# discretization in R with arules package

Tags: r, discretization

I am using arules package to discretize my continuous variables in data frame. 
I am using this particular line

discretize(data1,categories = 3)

but its giving me an error

Error in cut.default(x,k2) : k2 must be numeric

I am just trying to convert my continuous variables from "data1" data frame to 3 bins discrete variables. 
Any help would be appreciated...thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us your data1?

Answer (score 2):

Check this code:

```
library(arules)
data1 <- sample(1:30,100,replace = T)
res <- discretize(data1,categories = 3)
```

It works correctly.  Check

```
class(data1)
```

It should be **integer** or **numeric**

Comment: if data1 is data.frame then probably some column from data frame you want to discretize.  e.g.  res <- discretize(data1[[columnName]],categories = 3)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to discretize all columns:

```
data1.Disc <- as.data.frame(lapply(data1, 
                                   function(x) discretize(x, categories=5)
                                   )
                           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dplyr mutate_if function. This worked for me:

```
data1 <- data1 %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(discretize(., method="frequency", categories=3)))
```

Comment: This is a fine approach, but OP's problem seems to be that his target variables are not numeric (and so `is_numeric`, in this case, will not be true).

Comment: @cmaher disagree - OP's problem is that they called it *on the data frame* rather than on individual columns.